# How to use startActivityForResult with the stock Calculator app to process arithmetic terms

Tags: android

The stock android calculator app will process terms such as '(1-0.66)*100' to produce the result 34.

I want to use this term-processing ability to return a computed result to my app.

Has anyone any experience with this approach?

Comment: What's wrong with `double r = (1 - 0.66) * 100;` ?

Comment: There are plenty of Java libraries for mathematical expression parsing and interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can count on getting data back from the stock Android calculator application.

Look at the answer provided in this StackOverflow question for more information.

[Get Back Result from Android native Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578192/get-back-result-from-android-native-calculator)

Comment: Maybe not but this example doesn't show anything being passed to the calculator app - as if it is simply trying to display the app and then return the result of whatever the calculator is asked to do. Not really very applicable or practical ...

Comment: Looking at the source code for the stock Android calculator application it does not support receiving data from other applications, computing it, and then returning the value.

You can browse the source here: http://androidxref.com/source/xref/packages/apps/Calculator/