# Starting calculator, returning to activity that launched calc

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

I'm launching the device's standard calculator from an activity, but if I close the calculator, it doesn't return to the activity that launched the calculator. Do I have to set a certain FLAG?

Code:

```
public void LaunchDeviceCalculator(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> packages =new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);  
        for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {
        if( pi.packageName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("calcul")){
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
            map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
            packages.add(map);
    }
        }

        if(packages.size()>=1){
            String packageName = (String) packages.get(0).get("packageName");
            Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

            if (i != null)
              startActivity(i);
            } 
}
```

Comment: Depends how you're launching it. Show some code?

Comment: "I'm launching the device's standard calculator from an activity" -- there is no single "device's standard calculator" on Android. This is often replaced by device manufacturers, and there is no standard `Intent` action to open a calculator. Your code will open a random application that happens to have `calcul` in its package name, which is not a very intelligent algorithm. Expecting this code to open a calculator, let alone always return to your app when you "close" it (by means you failed to specify), is unrealistic.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so you're suggesting writing your own calculator?

Comment: I am suggesting that if the user wants to use a calculator, the user can go use a calculator without your assistance.

Comment: I think its what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578192/get-back-result-from-android-native-calculator

Comment: openintents.org used to have a registry where you could submit new intents. The "standard" calculator intent is org.openintents.action.CALCULATOR. I don't know how many calculator apps respond to it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching calculator can be done by the below code. Please check this link for more details: [Android Intents For App Integration (Call a Calculator, Play Video, Open an Editor)](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-intents-for-app-integration-call-a-calculator-play-video-open-an-editor/)

I haven't tried this yet but code seems quite simple and fine. Let me know if this works.

```
// activity name and package for stock calculator    
    private static final String CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.calculator2";    
    private static final String CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME = "com.android.calculator2.Calculator";
    public void launchCalculator() {   
         Intent intent = new Intent();   
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);   
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);  
         intent.setComponent(new Component Name(CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME, CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME));   
    try {   
         this.start Activity(intent); 
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException noSuchActivity) {  
         // handle exception where calculator intent filter is not registered  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, a third-party calculator handles this situation:
http://www.efalk.org/RpnCalcFinancial/

Search for Developers Notes.

The developer lists the Intent that will launch the app and the Intent and extras that are returned.

As far as I remember, it's free.

It does use Reverse Polish Notation aka RPN.

Comment: That's mine.  You should try `org.openintents.action.CALCULATOR`, it's a bit more standard. Both my free and paid calculators will respond to it.